# How to use expo-google-sign-in?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using the expo-google-sign-in in my expo app for login. However, I'm getting the error that expo-google-sign-in is not supported in expo client. How can I create a react native app that does hot reloading that I can debug the expo-google-sign-in at?

Answer (score 0):

GoogleSignIn can't be used in the Expo client, since the native GoogleSignIn library expects your `REVERSE_CLIENT_ID` in the `info.plist` at build-time, so that is expected.

This is only possible with standalone apps. You can use TestFlight to create a standalone .ipa to test on iOS which doesn’t require you to go through the review process. As for Android, you can create an apk and install it onto your device.

[Github issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4854)